# How to define a user (author) - OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I need help. I only need to be able to view one user for a post in OctoberCMS.

But all users will always show up to me.

Here's the code that works, but I don't know how to define it to work the way I need it.

idea: https://ibb.co/VM2Rrr3

```
public function getUserOptions()
{
    $result = [0 => 'indikator.news::lang.form.select_user'];
    $users = Db::table('backend_users')->orderBy('login', 'asc')->get()->all();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $name = trim($user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name);
        $name = ($name != '') ? ' ('.$name.')' : '';
        $result[$user->id] = $user->login.$name;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: what user do you want to get?

Comment: The user who creates the post.

Comment: what post? where is the post defined?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZGYGxVs
https://ibb.co/j5NhjdC

The post should only contain the user who created it.

Comment: yes so which post do you want to find for the user?

Comment: https://ibb.co/VM2Rrr3 Here I want only the user who creates the project to appear. No more options (another user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as user who is creating project is user who is currently logged in so we can use `current logged-in user` that.

```
use BackendAuth;

public function getUserOptions()
{
    // placeholder
    $result = [0 => 'indikator.news::lang.form.select_user'];

    // only back-end user which is currently logged in
    // it will be available always as we are in back-end :)
    $user = BackendAuth::getUser();
    $result[$user->id] = $user->login; // or $user->email;    

    return $result;
}
```

> It will get logged in user and show in drop-down for selection [ or even you skip place-holder to have only 1 selected option]

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.